# django annotate not working properly

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models `SaleItem` and `Product`. Here i want to get the count of the `products` in the `SaleItem` table . I used annotate but not getting the desired result

```
class SaleItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="sale_products")
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

views.py

```
SaleItem.objects.values("product__name").annotate(count=Count("product__name"))
```

when i tried this in shell. i am getting all the products with count 1

```
<QuerySet [{'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Rice'}, {'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Rice'}, {'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Mango'}, {'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Mango'}, {'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Mango'}, {'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Apple'}, {'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Apple'}, {'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Apple'}, {'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Apple'}, {'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Grape'}, {'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Grape'}, {'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Grape'}, {'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Grape'}, {'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Grape'}, {'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Grape'}, {'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Grape'}, {'count': 1, 'product__name': u'Grape'}]>
```

here i want the totalcount of the each Product in the SaleItem table. How can i do that. Somebody please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet

in the example it has this:

```
Each publisher, each with a count of books as a "num_books" attribute.
>>> from django.db.models import Count
>>> pubs = Publisher.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('book'))
>>> pubs
<QuerySet [<Publisher: BaloneyPress>, <Publisher: SalamiPress>, ...]>
>>> pubs[0].num_books
73
```

Applying it to your case, I think it should be something like this:

```
sale_items = SaleItem.objects.annotate(product_count=Count("product__name"))
```

then you can do

```
sale_items[0].product_count
```

this will return the product count assoicated with one sale item